# Closing an infowindow in Primefaces gmap

Tags: google-maps, jsf, primefaces, infowindow

I am using primefaces googlemap with markers and infowindow. The infowindow has a button on it. On the click of the button, I am invoking a method in the backing bean for processing. At the same time, I want to close the info window. I am using the close() method of infowindow, but that is refreshing my map. My backing bean is a ViewScoped bean and hence the refresh is not working well for me. Is there any better way to close an infowindow without refreshing the page? This is how my xhtml looks like.

```
<p:gmap center="21, 78" id="map" zoom="2" type="roadmap" style=" margin: 0 auto 0 auto;height: 500px"  model="#{sBean.mapModel}" widgetVar="mapVar">
    <p:ajax event="overlaySelect" listener="#{sBean.onMarkerSelect}" update="messages"/> 
        <p:gmapInfoWindow id="infoWindow" rendered="#{sBean.showInfoWindow}"> 
              ...........................................................


              <p:commandButton id="connect" value="Connect" actionListener="#{sBean.connect()}" onclick="infoWindow.close();"/> 
        </p:gmapInfoWindow>                              
</p:gmap>
```

Answer (score 0):

// get map instance
var map = PF('pfMapWidget').getMap();

// close the opening info window
map.infoWindow.close();